# CFHTTPMessageCopyAllHeaderFields with duplicate headers

Tags: ios, cookies, http-headers

I am trying to read the response headers in an `HTTP request`. I came to this method `CFHTTPMessageCopyAllHeaderFields` to read them, but I get a dictionary with only one entry for the header `[Set-Cookie]` what makes me think that this method is not combining the headers with same key and different values like the is this scenario, where the server sends to headers for 2 different cookies, both using the key `[Set-Cookie]`.

I also need the same for other headers like `[Vary]` and so on.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Did u try [response allHeaderFields], where response is NSHttpURLResponse.If you are dealing with CFNetwork level request then you can make a local request to a local socket with port 80 and read the HTTPHeaders.

Comment: I checked and the method combines correctly the headers prior add them to the dictionary, the problem seems related with some cache mechanism, when the cookies are received.